# JavaScript: click event for same class name

Tags: javascript

I've the following code snippet. The issue is `onclick` event doesn't fire for the second label, which has the same class as the first one. Why is that?
I searched online and found multiple solutions but all of them are in jQuery. But I want it in pure JavaScript. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here?

```js
var label = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
label[0].onclick = function() {
 console.log(true);
};
```

```html
<label class="text">Hello</label>
<label class="text">World!</label>
```

PS: I know this question has been asked here multiple times (but the solutions are for jQuery). So please don't mark this question as duplicate :/

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array (a collection) of nodes, and you're only applying the function to the first `[0]` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label` is an array of all the elements with class `text`, so `label[0]` will only apply to the first element in the document.  Simplest way to do it would probably be with a loop such as

```
for (var i = 0; i<label.length; i++){
    label[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log(true);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [event delegation](http://javascript.info/tutorial/event-delegation) :

```js
document.body.onclick = function (ev) {
  if (ev.target.getAttribute("class") == "text") {
    console.log(true);
  }
};
```

```html
<label class="text">Hello</label>
<label class="text">World!</label>
```

Thanks to event delegation new labels are also clickable :

```js
var nLabels = 2;

document.body.onclick = function (ev) {
  var newLabel;
  if (ev.target.getAttribute("class") == "text") {
    console.log(ev.target.textContent);
  } else if (ev.target.id == "btn-add-label") {
    newLabel = document.createElement("label");
    newLabel.setAttribute("class", "text");
    newLabel.textContent = " new label #" + (nLabels++);
    document.body.appendChild(newLabel);
  }
};
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn-add-label">Add label</button>
<label class="text">Hello</label>
<label class="text">World!</label>
```

Comment: it would be better to apply this approach to the first parent container if there would be a more complex DOM structure. But it's good direction to use a delegation, +1

Answer (score 0):

```
var label = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
for (var i = 0; i<label.length; i++) {
  label[i].oncllick = function () { console.log(true); };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var label = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
for (var i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
    label[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log(true);
    };
}
```