# Capture text inside a <p> using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I need to create a shopping cart. When I click the button "Add to Cart", the item in the  "p" should appear in the screen.

**PHP**

```
<?php foreach($product as $prods) { ?>
    <div class="prod">
          <p class="test"><?php echo $prods['name'] ?></p>
          <button type="submit" onclick="addProd()">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function addProd() {
    var test=  document.getElementsByClassName('test').innerText;
    alert(test);
}
```

Comment: Use `innerText` or `textContent`.  `.value` means a `<input value="">` of which you do not have.

Comment: your id is "test" and your getElementById is searching for "teste"

Comment: Also going off of the foreach loop, you are generating invalid markup by repeating ids.  So there is the attribute issue, the incorrect id issue, and the repeated ids issue.  This question has numerous issues.

Comment: First, you should use class instead of id attribute, then check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044669/javascript-click-event-for-same-class-name)

Comment: I don't know how to create a shopping cart, so, I can't display the products in the screen using this method?

Comment: display by alert?:) That is weird method to display products... of course you can, but it is useless and a very bad approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The p tag is not a object with value attribute, you should use:

```
/* to get unformated text content, including all elements in <p> tag like styles in text format, hidden elements etc. */
 var test=  document.getElementById('test').textContent;
    
/* or - to get the visible text from the <p> tag */
var test=  document.getElementById('test').innerText;
    
/* or - to get the all html included in the <p> tag */
var test=  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
```

but first of all you must change your PHP code, you generate multiple

tags with same ID, so there is no unique ID you can handle. So make them unique and try with:

PHP

```
<?php 
foreach($product as $prods) { 
$i=1;
 echo'<div class="prod">
          <p id="test'.$i.'">'.$prods['name'].'</p>
          <button type="submit" onclick="addProd('.$i.')">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>';
$i++;
} 
?>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function addProd(number) {
    var product_id='test'+number;
    var test=  document.getElementById(product_id).innerText;
    alert(test);
}
```

Comment: This isn't the only issue.

Comment: Sorry guys, my entire code is wrong. The alert just shows me the content of the first product, even if I click in another one. I don't know what to do, but thanks for the help!! xD ;)

Comment: sorry for my typos before, should work fine now ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think you misspeled "teste" and you should use textContent for this.

```
var test=  document.getElementById('test').textContent;
```

Comment: Nothing happends, i oppened console and it shows this error:

Cannot read property 'innerText' of null at addProd

Comment: there is a huge difference between textContent and innerText, for getting the text only innerText should be used

Comment: check what Agnitor44 mentioned, you have a typo in the getElementById, should be .getElementById('test') instead of .getElementById('teste')

Comment: This isn't the only issue.

Comment: that is true Taplar, foreach($product as $prods), you have plenty products with same ID, ID must be unique

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using inline bindings, I would suggest that you pass in the value you are trying to lookup, and cut out the middle man of trying to find it in another element.

```
<div class="prod">
    <p class="test"><?php echo $prods['name'] ?></p>
    <button type="submit" onclick="addProd('<?php echo $prods['name'] ?>')">Add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

There's no reason to lookup the value.  Just give it to the method.

Comment: could be a good solution, but we are not sure what's in $prods['name'] and it can break the onclick event, like f.ex.: Mike's Bike

Comment: $prods['name'] it's just the name of the product.

Answer (score -1):

PHP

```
 <?php 
foreach($product as $key => $prods) { 
 echo'<div class="prod">
          <p id="test'.$key.'">'.$prods['name'].'</p>
          <button type="submit" onclick="addProd('.$key.')">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>';
} 
?>

JAVASCRIPT

function addProd(number) {
    var test=  document.getElementById('test'+number).innerText;
    alert(test);
}
```